# how to regoize var JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json

consider this code:

```
        var data = JSON.stringify({
            id: _id,
            ReplyId: _idComment
        })
        openDialog(_url, data, $('#div-modal1'));

    function openDialog(url, Id, div) {
        //regoize  var Id is type JSON.stringify?

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "Get",
            data: { id: Id },
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result.status == false) {
                ShowMessage('warning', result.message, "error")

            } else {
                div.html(result);

                div.dialog("open");

            }
        });
    }
```

example:for array

if (grid instanceof Array)

i want code That regoize the variable is type JSON.stringify yes or no?

Comment: stringify returns a string...

Comment: Is regoize a real word?

Comment: Recognition type variable

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` does just that, returns a string:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 1});
// returns "{"a":1}"
```

So, if you want to test if you have a string that was generated via `JSON.stringify`, just test whether it is valid JSON using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
var is_json = true;

try {
  JSON.parse(id);
} catch (e) {
  // if we are here, `id` wasn't valid JSON
  is_json = false;
}

if (is_json) {
  // Run code knowing `id` is a JSON string
} else {
  // Otherwise, run code knowing `id` isn't a JSON string
}
```

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-OpssOXc318WGVlekwwb1lmNDA/view no answer if id=29 for exapmle picture